# How do I get R to work with spaces in a file path?

Tags: r, filepath, spaces, readxl

I believe a switch to OneDrive is causing some issues in various packages in R due to spaces being incorporated into the file path name. One shown below is the readxl package. Is there a way to get the package to read the spaces in the file path names? Or is it something other than the spaces that I might have overlooked?

Installation and the loading of the library work fine. However, when trying to import an excel file, it only works if I put the file in a location without spaces in the file path. I need the file to be in OneDrive so that it will be backed up.

```
install.packages("readxl")
library("readxl")

TRENDS_2020 <- read_excel("C:\\Users\\name03\\OneDrive - Specific Details Here (ABC)\\Backup_12_22_2020\\WQ_ALL_FINAL_WEBSITE_PIVOT_TRENDS_2020.xlsx")
```

I get the following error when running that:

```
Error in utils::unzip(zip_path, list = TRUE) : 
  zip file 'C:\Users\name03\OneDrive - Specific Details Here (ABC)\Backup_12_22_2020\TRENDS_2020.xlsx' cannot be opened
```

The following does work for the same file that I copy and pasted into my C drive:

```
TRENDS_2020 <-read_excel("C:\\TRENDS_2020.xlsx")
```

Comment: Probably not to do with spaces. Do you have the file open in Excel? That will cause an error.

Comment: I don't think the issue is the spaces--I would expect a "file not found" error if spaces were the issue.  OneDrive often causes permissions issues with files. Perhaps you can `file.copy` it in and out of OneDrive. Another thing to check with MS office files is to make sure they are not open in any office applications, as that can lock the file.

Comment: You could confirm the space issue by creating a local folder with a space in the name (not in OneDrive) and testing it there.

Comment: If this is really due to the spaces, you can try the **shortPathName** function.

Answer (score 0):

Zip {utils}

treated as if passed to system, if the filepaths contain spaces they must be quoted e.g. by shQuote.

[Statistical Data Analysis ETH Zurich](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/zip.html)